# How can we filter a list with multiple if condtion in Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list with some  objects. I need to perform linq in that list to get another list say "sublist", with following conditions
1)if the item status is "complete" and the completed date with in 5 days,include into sublist
2)if the item status is "pending" and due date less than 7 days ,include into sublist

How i can achieve this with a single linq query??
Thank you for your support in advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It's not clear what kind of problem you have here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IEnumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) method with a predicate that has your conditions.  Since I don't know your object model I'll make one to show as an example:

```
Public Class SomeObject
    Public Property Status As String
    Public Property Complete As DateTime?
    Public Property DueDate As DateTime?

    Public Sub New(strStatus As String, dteComplete As DateTime?, dteDueDate As DateTime?)
        Status = strStatus
        Complete = dteComplete
        DueDate = dteDueDate
    End Sub
End Class
```

Some data population:

```
Dim lstObjects As New List(Of SomeObject)

lstObjects.Add(New SomeObject("Complete", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)))
lstObjects.Add(New SomeObject("Pending", Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)))
lstObjects.Add(New SomeObject("Pending", Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)))
```

And this is how you can query it (returns two results):

```
Dim sublist As List(Of SomeObject) = lstObjects.Where(Function(target As SomeObject)
                                                          Dim bolMatch As Boolean = False

                                                          If (target.Status = "complete" AndAlso
                                                              target.Complete > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-5)) OrElse
                                                             (target.Status = "pending" AndAlso
                                                              target.DueDate < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(7)) Then
                                                              bolMatch = True
                                                          End If

                                                          Return bolMatch
                                                      End Function).ToList()
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If the answer was useful, please up vote.